# Show that on C[0,1] $d_1(f, g) ≤ d_∞(f, g) $

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Show that on C[0,1] $d_1(f, g) ≤ d_∞(f, g) $ where $d_1(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1}|f-g|$ and $d_\infty=sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)-g(t)|$ how do we show this? I am confused with a couple of steps in a solution I have.

I know that if I introduce $d_2=(\int_{0}^{1}|f-g|^2)^{1/2}$ I can show that $d_1\leq d_2$ by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, then I can use that $|f-g|^2 \leq sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)-g(t)|^2$ (is this a general result and how does it work?) then I have seen the next step is taking the integral of this to get $\int_{0}^{1}|f(s) − g(s)|^2 ≤sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)-g(t)|^2$ but how do we get this step why does the integral not affect the sup part at all?

Then putting it all together we have $d_1 \leq d_2 \leq d_\infty$ which obviously shows $d_1 \leq d_\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the trivial bound on integrals:
$$
\int_a^bf\mathrm dx\leq (b-a)\sup_{t\in [a,b]} \{f(t)\}
$$